# Batch convert wpd files to docx with LibreOffice

Tags: batch-file, docx, libreoffice, file-conversion, wordperfect

I'm trying to convert a bunch of wpd filed into docx with libreoffice, so far I have been able to achieve it but the resultant docx files are saved in just one folder (Ale) instead of Ale and its subdirectories, and what I want is for the docx files to be saved in the folder the wpd file are in. So far I have:

```
set path=%path%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program"
for /r %%f in (*.wpd) do (
soffice.exe -headless -convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" -outdir "S:\Temp\Ale" %%f)
```

Comment: Try with `-outdir "%%~dpf" "%%~nxf"`...

Comment: it didn't work, it keeps being saved in the same drectory.

Comment: Don't you need to state all the switches with *two* hyphens like `--outdir`?

Comment: You can use just 1 in windows.

Comment: I don't think this depends on the OS... Anyway, you are running yout script from directory `S:\Temp\Ale`, right? what about trying `for /r "S:\Temp\Ale" %%f in (*.wpd) do ( ... )`? or alternatively, omit the `--outdir` parameter and 1. insert `pushd "%%~ff"` *before* the `soffice.exe` command line and 2. insert `popd` *after* the `soffice.exe` command line (within the parentheses of the `for /r` loop)...

Comment: I can't omit -convert, convert is the parameter used by soffice.exe, without it there's no conversion at all.

Comment: Sure; I was talking about the `--outdir` parameter...

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @aschipfl said, go to the directory of each file and then do the conversion:

```sh
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "path=%path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program"

for /r %%f in (*.wpd) do (
    pushd %%~dpf
    soffice.exe -headless -convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" "%%f"
    popd
)
endlocal
```

Comment: yeah I'll do that. Thanks

Comment: Except your script just worked and I didn't have to place the script in every directory, it worked from the first one.

Comment: Well, yes, what I meant by "go to the directory" is that the script goes to each directory by using `pushd`.  Anyway, if it answered your question, then please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).